# Fetching JSON data from @RestContoller using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Why the html page doesn't load on specific requested URL and doesn't fetching data from JSON format?
[Result of opening api/reservations/all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7bJc.png)

Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/reservations")
public class ReservationController {

    private final ReservationService reservationService;

    @Autowired
    public ReservationController(ReservationService reservationService) {
        this.reservationService = reservationService;
    }
 @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Reservation> showAllReservations() throws SQLException {
        return reservationService.showAllReservations();
    }
}
```

HTML + Javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Reservations</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Fetch JSON data from REST controller
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/reservations/all")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          // Iterate over each object in the JSON array
          var formattedData = "";

          data.forEach((item) => {
            formattedData +=
              "<p>Reservation ID: " +
              item.id +
              "</p>" +
              "<p>Customer: " +
              item.customer.name +
              "</p>" +
              "<p>Email: " +
              item.customer.email +
              "</p>" +
              "<p>Check-in Date: " +
              item.dateCheckIn +
              "</p>" +
              "<p>Check-out Date: " +
              item.dateCheckOut +
              "</p>" +
              "<hr>"; 
          });
          // Update the HTML container with the formatted data
          var dataContainer = document.getElementById("data-container");
          dataContainer.innerHTML = formattedData;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    </script>
    <div id="data-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I checked URL correctness, controller seems fine, the files locates in different folders (templates for .html and src>java>package for controller).

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console, result shows as json on api/reservations/all, but I want to make it prettier using html/css/js, maybe it something wrong with html?

Comment: So what's the actual issue? Does the code work?

Comment: Controller works, but javascript doesn't fetch json result from controller and doesn't format it in html tags

Comment: So does the `fetch` not work at all (in which case check the console for errors) or is it getting the result but not formatting it the way you want?

Comment: I run app on Spring boot using Intellij IDEA, in this console and browser console there are no errors. Maybe is it something wrong with no linking contoller with html page, or because the javascript is embedded into an HTML document?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` in the second `.then` callback to check if you're actually getting the data.

Comment: I added `console.log(data)` in the second `.then` as you said. But there is no info in console. Maybe I linked files all wrong somehow? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have not configured it, but I will give it a try.

Comment: In your case, CORS is not a concern. according to your code `data` is supposed to be an array. Is it? `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` will print formatted data to your console. if it does not, something is wrong with your data returned by the url. Simpler way to check your data is open your console and observe the network. Also, if you take your `http://localhost:8080/api/reservations/all` and just run it on  browser or run a `wget` command you will print data if no issue with the url itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it worked now, the problem was that the html page would not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inattention, clicking on the button took me to `api/reservation/all` instead of `reservations.html` and so the javascript didn't work and didn't show the result. Thanks for your answers.